# Why does valueForKey throw an exception when used on dispatch_queue_t instance variable?

Tags: objective-c

**This is for unit testing purposes only**

I'm trying to access a dispatch_queue_t that is a protected instance variable of an objective C object for unit testing purposes.   I'm using valueForKey to access the protected instance variables that are objects, is there an equivalent call I can make for dispatch_queue_t?

Thank you

Edit: I've read that access to these values is possible, I just can't find a explanation of how.

Edit2: When I try calling valueForKey I get
2013-09-24 14:17:35.235 MyApp[7729:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key _queue.'

Edit3: I just tested and realized it should work with structs, the one that is throwing the exception is the retrieval of a dispatch_queue_t

Edit4: This was in code that is using Automatic Reference Counting

Comment: Do you mean that you can get to the ivar using `valueForKey:` but it returns an `NSValue` object with struct data?

Comment: It throws an exception, I edited above with more details but I now realize the exception comes from using valueForKey on a dispatch_queue_t instance variable.

Comment: Your best bet may be to see if there is a method already defined just not exposed.  (If the ivar is defined as a property, it is.)  You could define a category to expose the method and use that to retrieve the value for testing.

Comment: The ivar isn't defined as a property and modifying it to a property for the sake of accessing it in unit tests seems like a bad idea when there isn't any other purpose to making it a property :/

Comment: `-Weverything` hates ivars, that could be a reason.  You may try `object_getInstanceVariable`

Comment: It says that function isn't available thanks to autocounting haha.

It's an interesting problem I learned a bit by trying to work around, I think I'll just let that part go untested rather than mutate the code to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found:

The alternative way to access the instance variable is with the following code using object_getIvar:

```
Ivar queueIvar = class_getInstanceVariable([_myObject class], "_queue");
_privateQueue = (__bridge dispatch_queue_t)(object_getIvar(_myObject, queueIvar));
```

Comment: `object_getIvar` returns `id`, which is OK for `dispatch_object_t`, but real structs may cause problems. Did you try `object_getInstanceVariable`?

Comment: Yeah, I got a different exception saying it could no be used in code that was utilizing autocounting (I think thats what it said)

Comment: Ah, I see. It's _Automatic Reference Counting_ or ARC ;) If your solution works, then use it. But of course **only for testing purposes!**

Comment: Yeah, violating scoping for any purposes just feels dirty. But this is utilizing mock objects which is a new realm for me and interesting and this seems like a pretty thoroughly awesome way to test code.

I wish there was a directive you could execute that would allow a class to break scoping for unit testing though, any refactoring will break these unit tests

Answer (score 2):

**Use the same `-valueForKey:` as for objects.**

Calling `-valueForKey:` will always return you an object, but in case of accessing non-object types, the value is wrapped in `NSValue` object. In case of structs it's `NSValue` directly, in case of numbers (`int`, `float`) it uses `NSNumber` subclass.

After you got `NSValue`, this is how you unwrap the struct:

```
NSValue *value = [object valueForKey:@"key"];
struct Something s;
[value getValue:&s];
// `s` contains the desired struct
```

Comment: I found out the problem is actually the retrieval of a dispatch_queue_t,  trying to use valueForKey on it throws an exception. (Very thorough answer btw, ty)

Comment: That' interesting. But you know that `dispatch_object_t` can be treated like `id`? It has `isa` field just like `NSObject` and you can actualy send messages to it. But that doesn't explain the exception.